# How to convert field of the list item via custom Struts type converter?

Tags: java, struts2, type-conversion, struts

I need to implement custom conversion for `ID` field in `Company` and `Employee` classes. I've already implemented custom converter extended from `StrutsTypeConverter` and it is successfully used to convert `Company.ID` field, but it does not work for `Employee.ID`.

Seems like the main problem is in conversion properties file. How should I specify converter class for employee ID field in conversion properties file?

**`MyAction-conversion.properties`:**

```
company.id = com.struts2.convertors.MyCustomConverter
company.??????.id = com.struts2.convertors.MyCustomConverter
```

**`MyAction`:**

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
 
    private Company company;
 
    public Company getCompany () {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany (Company company) {
        this.company= company;
    }
    @Override
    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**`Company`:**

```
public class Company {

    private ID id;
 
    private List<Employee> employees;
 
    // getters and setters
}
```

**`Employee`**

```
public class Employee{

    private ID id;
 
    private String name;
 
    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[TypeConversion Annotation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/typeconversion-annotation.html):**

This annotation is used for class and application wide conversion rules.

The TypeConversion annotation can be applied at property and method level.

```
 @TypeConversion(converter = “com.test.struts2.MyConverter”)
 public void setAmount(String amount) 
 {
    this.amount = amount;
 }
```

This annotation specifies the location of one of my converters. literally, by using this annotation, I register my class com.test.struts2.MyConverter as a converter, and gets executed every time when setAmount(String amount) method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following by adding a converter for the `ID` type to the `xwork-conversion.properties` file

```
com.struts2.ID = com.struts2.convertors.MyCustomConverter
```