# Data type converter not working with embedded object in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, type-conversion

I'm creating a data type converter within Struts 2 framework and got the problem below:

in the action conversion property file, I need to specify a property like this:

```
foo.field1.field2 = coverterClassName
```

`field1` is embedded object within `foo`, which has `field2` as one of the fields.

I have tried everything and couldn't make this working unless I put the property file

into same package as class `Foo`, which hooks up the struts2 with model class.

Has anyone had this problem before and is there any other solution for it?

Comment: You can apply type converter for the whole application: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-ApplyingaTypeConverterforanapplication.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing a *class wide conversion*, your conversion property file should be

> in the same location of the **classpath** as the target bean.

if your target bean is an action bean, then it should be in the same package as the action class. More about it [Applying a Type Converter to a bean or model](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html#applying-a-type-converter-to-a-bean-or-model).

You might also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17900293/573032) answer for how to apply *application wide conversion* to your field type. Note, you can do the same [type conversion using annotations](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion-annotation.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply. My problem is that I have to implement two converters for the same object. So the glbal converter is not the option. Secondly, I did put property file in the same package of Action, which is not working. But If I put the file in the same package of the bean class, then it works but couple the struts2 with model project. Any other solution?

Comment: What kind of *other* solution do you want?

Comment: I still want a converter applied to action class instead of model class. In other words, the property file should be in the same package of action class instead of model class. Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you just copy a property file to the location of your bean? If not using a global conversion properties, did you explore the last option using annotations?

Comment: that's what I am trying to avoid because the bean class is in seperate project from the web project. I have also tried the annotation, but it didn't work.

Comment: If it didn't work then you are doing something wrong. Edit the question and show what are you doing.